# Excel- How to find average from from certain values onwards?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQQt.png)

Looking at the above image, I am wondering how do I find the average starting at a number that matches certain criteria? For example, given the range J3:Q3, how would I start find the averaging after a number is greater than 50 (so in this example L3:Q3)?

Comment: is VBA an option ? will be much easier...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custome made Function in VBA in your Worksheet that you can call it from your worksheet.

In your Excel Worksheet you need to type

```
=Average_Cells(first_cell_for_average, value_above)
```

**first_cell_for_average** - you can put A3, the function will handle the rest.

**value_above** = in your post it's 50, you can modify it later to whatever value you want.

The Function Code:

```
Public Function Average_Cells(ByRef first_Cell As Range, larger_Than As Long) As Double

' Row 3 in your post
last_col = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, ActiveSheet.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
first_Col = first_Cell.Cells(1, 1).Column

For col = first_Col To last_col
    If Cells(3, col).Value > larger_Than Then
        GoTo Exit_For
    End If
Next

Exit_For:
Average_Cells = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Cells(3, col), Cells(3, last_col)))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Hack-y method:

Fill in J4 with

```
=IF(J3>50, J3, '')
```

And then copy it until Q4.

Then fill in J5 with

```
=AVERAGE(J4:Q4)
```

Comment: This is actually pretty smart, the problem is I have thousands of rows. I could always do it to the right of the row, but I'm looking to get a formulaic way to do this. I'm actually going to use this to solve my problem, but I hope someone else comes along with a "real" answer. Thanks for the help!